# C++ Make a class to act as a specific data type

Tags: c++, class, types, mfc

In MFC I see it's possible to pass `CStringA/CStringW` to functions that get `CHAR*/WCHAR*`

So for example how it is possible to create a class to act as `unsigned char*` or `int` for the functions that get `unsigned char*` or `int` as argument ?

Comment: Take a look to operator overloaing http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create some means of automatic conversion of your class to the type you need. The easiest way is to create a cast operator, e.g.:

```
operator int()
{
   ...
   return <the int value based of your object>;
}
```